# GLib syntax errors, while compiling libnice with latest GLib for win32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtk, glib, libnice

Some necessary background:

Libnice (p2p library) was meant to be compiled using 2.28 Glib (here's win32 compilation readme https://github.com/jcaden/libnice/blob/master/README.win32),
BUT the official example
(this one http://cgit.collabora.com/git/user/kakaroto/libnice.git/plain/examples/sdp-example.c),
implementing compiled before libnice, obviously was written using latest glib stuff.
I assume, it is possible to rewrite example for the older one, but latest glib is more elegant and cool all around, that's why I got a wish to use it.

Now, my question:

While trying to compile Libnice using latest GLib (got it from here http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php) for win32, using Visual Studio 2010, I encounter some syntax errors (Many of them). 
You can see log here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/71e2a80e57eb4b8ae6c1
 Is it fixable, and how?

P.S: to use latest GLib, I downloaded same stuff, that was described in readme; i.e Glib dev and runtime and zlib and gettext runtime.

Comment: Why did you say it was written using latest glib stuff? I did not notice anything recent in the provided code. Building GLib from source is quite straight forward if you use a POSIX environment (I'd vote for Cygwin) but directly using Visual C++ is quite challenging. See http://wiki.gnome.org/GTK+/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack for hints.

Comment: Maybe not latest, but, well obviously newer, that one, supposed to be compiled with (2.28)
It uses glib streams, GMutex and GCond, in the way as it described in the latest GLib (in 2.28 GStaticMutex must be use instead of GMutex, to work without initialisation, and GCond must be initialised somewhere anyway - in the younger glib don't need to.)
Wait a moment, and how building Glib can help me, if i got problems with building Libnice, using Glib?

Comment: All API you are referring to are presents in GLib basically since 2.0.0. Also keep in mind `g_thread_init` is (maybe was) called by `g_type_init` since glib 2.24.

Comment: The above link provides some useful hints on compiling GLib and **related** libraries on Visual C++ compilers: fill free to ignore them.

Comment: Thank You for your advise, I will look at thise instructions)